# PyQt5 Signal is not going to connect

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

So I'm currently working on a PyQT5 GUI, and I've been stuck with this for hours.
I want `signal1` connect to `slot3` but nothing happen. I'm really confused. Why can't it connect to `slot3`?

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore as core
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as widget


class MainApp(widget.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, argv):
        widget.QApplication.__init__(self, argv)
        self.window1 = Window1()
        self.window2 = Window2()
        self.window1.signal1.connect(self.window2.slot3)


class Window1(widget.QMainWindow):
    signal1 = core.pyqtSignal()
    signal2 = core.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        widget.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.slot1()
        self.show()

    def slot1(self):
        self.signal1.emit()
        print('slot1 connected')

    def slot2(self):
        print('slot2 connected')


class Window2(widget.QMainWindow):
    signal3 = core.pyqtSignal()
    signal4 = core.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        widget.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.show()

    def slot3(self):
        print('slot3 connected')

    def slot4(self):
        print('slot4 connected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It works as expected, the signal is emitted before you create the instance of Window2, hence you don't see 'slot3 connected'. You can maybe use  `QTimer.singleShot(1, lambda: self.signal1.emit())`.

Comment: I've try your solution and it works. Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem was that you were trying to emit before GUI loop. It might not be because u created the window2 after.

Comment: Yes, it is because the connection is done *after* the instance creation, which also is responsible of emitting the signal. There are rare cases for which a class emits an internal signal in the `__init__`, and that's because obviously that signal could only be connected *after* the initialization. Since the code of the example is pretty abstract, it's hard to provide a *proper* solution other than using a timer. Besides that, all `slot` functions should print "slot called", not "connected": slots are executed when the signal is emitted, not when it's connected.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Because in "slot1", i have some condition need to be check. If that condition is True, it will connect to "slot3", and that condition need to be checked right after main GUI start. So how should i do to archieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because the signal is emitted before connection. The signals that are emitted at a given moment will only be heard by the slots that have been connected before, the new connections will not be notified.

One possible solution is to use a QTimer:

```
core.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.signal1)
```

In the code, the `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)` is invoked an instant after the eventloop takes control and that is an instant after the synchronous logic is executed (where the connection code is).